# How to sort my ListView by my Long parameter of my Note Object

Tags: android, listview, sorting

Hi i'm new with ArrayAdapters and i need to sort my ListView by my Long parameter of my Note Object, i have tried to sort somehow my listView by DateModified which is Long parameter but with no result... ***The action should happen when i press the sort, from Menu.***

Can someone help me with this issue, i'll be thankful!

This is the code of my activity

```
public class NoteListActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
NotesAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_list);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_notes);

    adapter = new NotesAdapter(NoteListActivity.this, generateNoteList());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
private OnItemClickListener onListItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {


private ArrayList<Note> generateNoteList() {
    final ArrayList<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<Note>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Note note = new Note();
        note.setTitle("Title" + i);
        note.setDateCreated(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        note.setDateModified(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        noteList.add(note);
    }
    return noteList;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.note_list_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final int clickedItemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (clickedItemId) {
        case R.id.add:
            return true;

        case R.id.sort_list:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `Note` class with `Comparable` and put code for  `compareTo` for ex:

```
class Note implements Comparable<Note>{
..
...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Note n) {  
      return this.modifiedDate-n.modifiedDate;
    }

}
```

Create a function in your `Adapter`  to sort items:

```
public void sort(){
Colllections.sort(noteList);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And `onClick` of sort button just call:

```
adapter.sort();
```

If you want to sort based on Different fields just implement Comparators for each field for ex:

```
class DateCreatedComaparator implements Comparator<Note>{
    public int compare(Note n1,Note n2){
       return n1.dateCreated-n2.dateCreated; 
    }
}
```

and in your sort function:

```
public void sort(){
   Colllections.sort(noteList,new DateCreatedComaparator());
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: when i write public boolean compareTo<Note>(Note n), it says ... 
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
  construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token "<", = expected and Void methods cannot return a value

Comment: just write compareTo(Note n)

Comment: please check my edited ans made a mistake the first time change your compareTo function to new one